# After updating to cypress 12.0.0, my test is throwing an error in the cypress-if package

Tags: cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

After updating to cypress 12.0.0, I get the following error, how can I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypress has split commands that return elements into a "queries" category and internally implemented them differently.

This was partly to handle **"detached from DOM"** errors better and more automatically.

The official word is the `Cypress.Commands.overwrite()` function was left out of the new query API due to the complexity, but they will consider adding it (back?) in if there are enough use-cases presented.

Therefore, you should contribute your use-case to the issue [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25078) if you wish to continue using `cypress-if` and also keep up-to-date with Cypress versions.

**Note**, you can still add new commands to Cypress, and you can still overwrite some commands just not `cy.get()`, `cy.find()`, and `cy.contains()`.

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting commands in v12.0.0 can't be done right now. Here is the github issue.
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25078